# add a parsed list item to another list

Tags: java, android

i am working on a xml parsing app- news app.

I've parsed the xml file and transformed it to the listView, and when i click the news i see more detailed info about it. I'd like to implement the "add to favorites" button so that it appears in a list in favorites tab (i've implemented the favorites tab in the tabhost in main activity), can anybody help me to do this? (I don't know how to implement action bar button (add to favorites) and how by clicking it to add it to a listview). Thanks!!!!

here is the code for listItemClicked

```
package com.example.andrian.jurnaltv;




public class ListItemClicked extends ActionBarActivity {

static Bundle extras;

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
static ImageLoader imageLoader;
static DisplayImageOptions options;




ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_item_clicked);


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new     SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    //Setup the ImageLoader, we'll use this to display our images
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new     ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(config);

    //Setup options for ImageLoader so it will handle caching for us.
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .build();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}



public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}


public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {


    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View rootView =    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_item_clicked, container, false);


        TextView pDate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        pDate.setText( extras.getString("pdate") );


        TextView ptitle = (TextView)    rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        ptitle.setText(extras.getString("pname"));


        TextView pnText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        pnText.setText( extras.getString("pText"));




        //Setup a listener we can use to swtich from the loading indicator     to the Image once it's ready
        ImageLoadingListener listener = new ImageLoadingListener(){



            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {
                // i/ndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                // iconImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1, FailReason arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };

        //Load the image and use our options so caching is handled.
        final ImageView iconImg = (ImageView)       rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageLoader.displayImage( extras.getString("pImage"), iconImg,     options, listener);



        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```